# How do I get the name of a flow from within a task in Prefect?

Tags: prefect

I'm not sure if this is possible, since flow names are assigned later when a flow is actually run (aka, "creepy-lemur" or whatnot), but I'd like to define a Prefect task within a flow and have that task collect the name of the flow that ran it, so I can insert it into a database table. Has anyone figured out how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the flow run name and ID from the context:

```py
import prefect
from prefect import task, flow


@task
def print_task_context():
    print("Task run context:")
    print(prefect.context.get_run_context().task_run.dict())


@flow
def main_flow():
    print_task_context()
    print("Flow run context:")
    print(prefect.context.get_run_context().flow_run.dict())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_flow()
```

Here are more resources on Prefect Discourse about setting custom run names:

- https://discourse.prefect.io/tag/task_run_name
- https://discourse.prefect.io/tag/flow_run_name

Comment: kinda weird tho. I get `AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'get_run_context'`  Ahhh...I'm not on version 2.0 yet. Maybe that's it.

Comment: yup, exactly, the example is using Prefect 2.0

Comment: Is there any way to get the flow name inside a task? I see only the flow_run_id attribute is available

Comment: @AnnaGeller same question: how do you get the flow name from within a task?

Answer (score 4):

For anyone facing this issue with prefect 2, you can import the FlowRunContext from a task like this:

```
from prefect.context import FlowRunContext

@task
def my_task():
    flow_run_name = FlowRunContext.get().flow_run.dict().get('name')
```

Source:
https://docs.prefect.io/latest/concepts/runtime-context/

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can also access this information from the [`runtime` context](https://docs.prefect.io/latest/guides/runtime-context/#accessing-runtime-information) object/module (introduced in Prefect 2):

```py
from prefect import flow, task
from prefect import runtime


@task
def my_task():
    task_name = runtime.task_run.name
    flow_run_name = runtime.flow_run.name
```